# Parse Email Verification - Does not activate

Tags: parse-platform

Whenever I flip the switch for "Verify User Emails" it tells me "service unavailable" and proceeds to flip the switch back.  Is there something I am missing?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not customer support for your favorite company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I found:

Delete your app over and over again until one of the apps you create lets you flip the switch.  Took me about 4-6 tries to finally get one that works.